# How do I get the proper amount of nodes in my org-roam?

Tags: org-roam

I came across two ways of getting the number of nodes in my org-roam system/database.

1. querrying the sqlite database directly:

```
#+begin_src sqlite :db (eval org-roam-db-location)
select count(*) from nodes ;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 183
```

2. using the function from `org-roam`

The documentation stats that `org-roam-node-list` "return(s) all nodes stored in the database as a list of org-roam-nodes".

```
#+begin_src elisp
(length (org-roam-node-list))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 215
```

I am wondering why I have different results and which one is the "right" one?

Comment: Take a look at the source code of `org-roam-node-list`: the query it runs is much more complicated than the one above. That probably explains the diffferent number, although you might want to run that query by hand to verify. Which is "right", I'll leave for you to decide :-)